# Как заставить соцсеть дождаться загрузки контента с JS сайта

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Есть сайт крутится на NuxtJS но это не важно.

Если попытаться поделиться ссылкой на сайт, то соцсети получают js данные, и не дожидаются загрузки контента. Хотя на самом сайте крутится лоадер, соцсеть считает страницу уже загруженной. Хотя данные подгрузятся позже с базы.

Как подружить их? И касается это любой соцсети.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт, если кто то будет искать решение, то нужно использовать хук asyncData [официальная ссылка](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data)

По сути это те данные которые будут получены до отображения страницы. Мой пример таков:

```
  async asyncData({ store, params }) {
    store.dispatch("loaderOn");
    await store.dispatch("news/getNews", { id: params["id"] });
    store.dispatch("loaderOff");
  }
```